# Using the Arctic SDI WMTS with cartopy and matplotlib

Tags: python, wmts, matplotlib, cartopy, spatial-data-infrastructure

I am trying to use the Arctic SDI topographic basemap (https://arctic-sdi.org/services/topografic-basemap/) with cartopy + matplotlib in python, but seemingly without success. It seems that for some reason the map bounds projection fails when converting from PlateCarree to any of the epsg codes that the service provides tiles in (EPSG 3571 to 3576).

Example:

```py
from owslib.wmts import WebMapTileService
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

proj = ccrs.epsg(3571)
source = "http://basemap.arctic-sdi.org/mapcache/wmts/?"

wmts = WebMapTileService(source)
layer = list(wmts.contents)[0]

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10), subplot_kw={"projection": proj})
ax.add_wmts(wmts, layer)
ax.set_extent([15, 16, 69, 70], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

gives the output

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell 5 line 1
     12 f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10), subplot_kw={"projection": proj})
     13 ax.add_wmts(wmts, layer)
---> 14 ax.set_extent([15, 16, 69, 70], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

File cartopy\mpl\geoaxes.py:872, in GeoAxes.set_extent(self, extents, crs)
    865     raise ValueError(
    866         'Failed to determine the required bounds in projection '
    867         'coordinates. Check that the values provided are within the '
    868         f'valid range (x_limits={self.projection.x_limits}, '
    869         f'y_limits={self.projection.y_limits}).')
    871 print([x1, x2])
--> 872 self.set_xlim([x1, x2])
    873 self.set_ylim([y1, y2])

File matplotlib\axes\_base.py:3664, in _AxesBase.set_xlim(self, left, right, emit, auto, xmin, xmax)
   3662         raise TypeError("Cannot pass both 'right' and 'xmax'")
   3663     right = xmax
-> 3664 return self.xaxis._set_lim(left, right, emit=emit, auto=auto)

File matplotlib\axis.py:1210, in Axis._set_lim(self, v0, v1, emit, auto)
   1207 name = self._get_axis_name()
   1209 self.axes._process_unit_info([(name, (v0, v1))], convert=False)
-> 1210 v0 = self.axes._validate_converted_limits(v0, self.convert_units)
   1211 v1 = self.axes._validate_converted_limits(v1, self.convert_units)
   1213 if v0 is None or v1 is None:
   1214     # Axes init calls set_xlim(0, 1) before get_xlim() can be called,
   1215     # so only grab the limits if we really need them.

File matplotlib\axes\_base.py:3585, in _AxesBase._validate_converted_limits(self, limit, convert)
   3582     converted_limit = converted_limit.squeeze()
   3583 if (isinstance(converted_limit, Real)
   3584         and not np.isfinite(converted_limit)):
-> 3585     raise ValueError("Axis limits cannot be NaN or Inf")
   3586 return converted_limit

ValueError: Axis limits cannot be NaN or Inf
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!